# Переменная не изменяет значение

Tags: python

Проблема заключается в том, что по идее переменная `lowest` должна изменять своё значение, как и `highest` (с ней всё получается), но почему то этого не происходит.
Выставляю код вам на обозрение:

```
digits = []
sum = 0
lowest = 0
highest = 0

while True:
    digit = input('enter a number or Enter to finish: ')
    if digit == '':
        break
    Digit = int(digit)
    digits.append(Digit)
    sum += Digit
    if len(digits) == 0:
        lowest = Digit
        highest = Digit
    elif highest < Digit:
        highest = Digit
    elif lowest > Digit:
        lowest = Digit

print('numbers: ', digits)
print('count =', len(digits), 'sum =', sum, 'lowest =', lowest, 'highest =', highest, 'mean =', sum/len(digits))
```

Вывод программы такой:

> enter a number or Enter to finish: 43
>   enter a number or Enter to finish: 324
>   enter a number or Enter to finish: 2
>   enter a number or Enter to finish: 5
>   enter a number or Enter to finish: 65
>   enter a number or Enter to finish: 757
>   enter a number or Enter to finish: 33
>   enter a number or Enter to finish: 423
>   enter a number or Enter to finish:
>   numbers:  [43, 324, 2, 5, 65, 757, 33, 423]
>   count = 8 sum = 1652 lowest = 0 highest = 757 mean = 206.5

Comment: У вас в коде опечатка, после 'highest =' должна запятая идти (проблему это не решает)

Comment: Блин, а я думаю, где там syntax error...)))

Comment: Исправил. (pass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Условие `if len(digits) == 0` у Вас не выполняется никогда, т.к. вы добавлете число еще ДО его проверки. Просто переместите `digits.append(Digit)` в конец цикла, и все заработает.

П.С. Если ввести отрицательное число - должно заработать и так)))

П.П.С. `highest` также определится неверно, если все числа - отрицательные.

Рабочий код:

```
digits = []
sum = 0
lowest = 0
highest = 0

while True:
    try:
        digit = input('enter a number or Enter to finish: ')
    except:
        break
    if digit == '':
        break
    Digit = int(digit)
    sum += Digit
    if len(digits) == 0:
        lowest = Digit
        highest = Digit
    elif highest < Digit:
        highest = Digit
    elif lowest > Digit:
        lowest = Digit
    digits.append(Digit)

print 'numbers: ', digits
# print lowest, highest
print 'count =', len(digits), 'sum =', sum, 'lowest =', lowest, 'highest =', highest, 'mean =', sum/len(digits)
```

Вывод консоли:

```
D:\Python>python test002.py
enter a number or Enter to finish: 43
enter a number or Enter to finish: 324
enter a number or Enter to finish: 2
enter a number or Enter to finish: 5
enter a number or Enter to finish: 65
enter a number or Enter to finish: 757
enter a number or Enter to finish: 33
enter a number or Enter to finish: 423
enter a number or Enter to finish:
numbers:  [43, 324, 2, 5, 65, 757, 33, 423]
count = 8 sum = 1652 lowest = 2 highest = 757 mean = 206
```

Comment: В таком случае переменная _lowest_  принимает значение первого элемента списка, а при последующих проходах цикла оно не меняется. Проблема исправилась лишь частично.

Comment: Только что проверил Ваш код с перемещением строки append - все работает. Код буквально скопипастил (исправил print'ы - у меня 2-й питон)

Comment: Думаю вам стоило проверять в 3-ем питоне, т. к. у меня до сих пор переменная 'lowest' принимает значение первого элемента списка.

Comment: Не имеет значения - отличие только в print. Этого просто не может быть. Вставлю в ответ рабочий код - проверьте. Просто сейчас на винде удобнее, а там только 2-й

Comment: Вывод: numbers:  [546, 4535, 3452, 32342, 3346, 4563, 452342, 4523, 546, 546]; count = 10 sum = 506076 lowest = 546 highest = 452342 mean = 50607.

Comment: @АлександрИванов, а что не так? 546 - на самом деле минимум. П.С. Успел проверить на 3-ем - все работает. Можно, не перенося строку изменить условие на `if len(digits) == 1`. На 2-ом пришлось еще try вставить, а то на `EOF` ругался, на 3-ем все ОК у Вас.

Comment: Вы криво поправили код, из-за чего значение Digit меняется до его добавления список. Пришлось разорвать единый алгоритм разветвления на два. Однако проблема так и не решилась.

Comment: @АлександрИванов Где оно меняется? Еще раз - я просто скопипастил Ваш код, и перенес ОДНУ строку. На try/except внимания не обращайте - это всего лишь особенность 2-ого питона.

Comment: Вроде бы все правильно, к слову mean будет округляться в Python 2 из-за целочисленного деления.

Comment: У меня числа в списке, которые меньше первого элемента в списке становятся им. Может вы просто попробуете обратить внимание на ваш ввод и выводимый список?

Comment: @АлександрИванов, Вы меня извините, но Ваш же код у меня работает и во 2-ом и в 3-ем Питоне одинаково ПРАВИЛЬНО. Значит, либо у Вас неправильный питон (маловероятно), либо Вы где-то опечатались.

Comment: Действительно ваш код работает с соответствующими поправками. П. С. Оказалось всё из-за того, что поменял местами lowest и Digit в 19-ой строке.

Comment: @АлександрИванов, как я и писал - банальная опечатка.